# SHA mismatch error when sfdx update command is executed

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-cli

Salesforce CLI is recently installed in my system and it is showing the following information on every command.

```
! sfdx-cli: update available from 6.55.1-be0b3dc4c4 to 7.22.0-de5c6ecff8
```

I am not able to create project for the same. I have also checked by setting the disable auto update as ture in the environment variables.

When I am running sfdx update, the update is failing with the following error

```
SHA mismatch: expected <alpha-numaric id> to be <different alpha-numaric id>
```

Comment: Can you try with the environment variable trick from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_update_cli.htm? Skip the autoupdate step? If you're on windows it could be just `set SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=true`

Comment: Already tried. Mentioned in my description as well.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to arise from time to time, and I got hit by this today. In my case there was no difference whether run in standard perms or as administrator.

In order to fix this, Salesforce product management [suggested](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/189) on github to do a full uninstall and reinstall of the CLI.

I was trying to avoid doing this so instead I did the following:

```sh
> sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx
> sfdx update
```

That worked for me as an alternative to doing the full on uninstall/reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

If on windows try running as an admin.  That seemed to solve my problem (on Windows Server 12).

If you're on a Linux machine try running with sudo rights.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows OS, **sfdx update needs admin privilege**. You should have run the command prompt as admin and then try for sfdx update. I just did that and was able to complete sfdx update.